# LLVM For a Recipe-style language

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

I want to learn LLVM.  And I want to try to use the following cookbook style language to do so:

```
Ingredients:
    x-unit Flour
    y-unit Yeast
    z-unit Water
    a-unit Sugar

Instructions:
    bowl = mix flour with yeast for 30 seconds
    bowl = mix bowl with sugar for 25 seconds
    bowl = mix bowl with water for 1 minute
    heat bowl for 3 hours
    dough = split bowl into 3 parts
    heat dough[n] at 450 f for 1 hour
```

As it's a learning experience, I'm not sure if LLVM would be capable of handling a language where time/volume are dimensions that can be computed upon.  And after reading through some of the documentation, I'm not entirely sure if this is the right tool for what I want to do.

I would like to take this language, compile it, and transform it to valid C/Python code so I can use a RPi or Arduino to execute the program.  Essentially I want to attempt to automate basic recipes by expressing them in this language and run a small kitchen from this.

To posit the question a different way: How does LLVM handle time-specific instructions.  So how would I express in LLVM IR the instruction `mix flour with yeast for 30 seconds`?

Comment: LLVM is a compiler-backend. If you have concrete plans for transforming your language into machine code, this would be involved. If you only want to detect or interpret the language, you need a compiler frontend (lexer, parser, analyzer, interpreter).

Comment: I'm not worried about the front-end.  I was planning on using `flex`/`bison` to handle it for me.  What I wasn't sure of is how to represent the time/volume dimension in LLVM.  I do know that it makes a lot of assumptions about the architecture of the execution.  So I wasn't sure how I'd represent time or volume within the context of LLVM, e.g., how do I tell LLVM to do some task for some time?

Comment: I think you should clarify what the compiled program should do. Building a model of the language is again only compiler frontend.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Is that better?

Comment: No. Just what does your RPi do, when it executes the program? It certainly does not bake your bread? Does it display the recipe?

Comment: The kitchen then becomes my machine, controlled by the RPi.  In a theoretical world, assume it does everything.  It is capable of loading the flour and yeast in the bowl and actuating a kitchen aid mixer for 30 seconds.  Then it knows to add the sugar and continuing mixing, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not sure if LLVM would be capable of handling a language where time/volume are dimensions that can be computed upon.

In general you can do anything in LLVM that you can do in C. After all clang compiles C to LLVM.

> I would like to take this language, compile it, and transform it to valid C/Python code

If you want to generate C and/or Python, just do that. You go through LLVM if the target is machine code/assembly. LLVM does not help you in generating C or Python code.

> How does LLVM handle time-specific instructions

You just call the corresponding OS or libc functions (or the equivalent on your embedded platform) - just like you would in C. For example to wait 30 seconds on a POSIX system, you'd generate a call to `sleep`:

```
call i32 (i32) @sleep(i32 30)
```

You'd also have to generate a declaration for the function:

```
declare i32 @sleep(i32)
```

So basically you do the exact same thing you'd do in a hand-written C program, except with LLVM's syntax for function calls and declarations instead of C's.